# Python: Code for program to add itself to start up (Windows)

Tags: python, windows

I found that a program needs to add itself to `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` for it to start up automatically. But how would I do this not knowing the person's user profile?

Also, I read something about the program being added to the system registry? How would I do that?

I found this code to copy the file

```
os.rename("path/to/current/myfile.exe", "path/to/new/desination/for/myfile.exe")
```

But I don't know the path to current file. Everyone has a different username so `/Bob/Downloads` will not be where the file is located and I don't know what `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` name will be on their computer.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I'm testing this on Windows 7; it should also work on other Windows but I can't promise.

The values for %ALLUSERSPROFILE% and %USERPROFILE% are in os.environ.

If your code is running as the user who downloaded it, you can therefore do something like:

```
import os
aup = os.environ.get("ALLUSERSPROFILE")
up = os.environ.get("USERPROFILE")
if aup and up:
  os.rename(os.path.join(up,"Downloads","myfile.exe")),os.path.join(aup,"Start menu","Programs","startup","myfile.exe"))
else:
    print("Oops, couldn't look up stuff in os.environ")
```

Note that I don't think there's an easy way to get another user's profile; if you're running on a desktop and are running as say alice but want to get bob's directory, you can presumably cheat and do
`alt_user_profile = os.path.join(up,"..","bob")` 
(i.e. assume that the users are all in the same parent directory); if you're running somewhere in which user profiles are not all in the same parent, you might need to look into a Windows specific API.  (And of course, there may be permissions issues with trying to reach into another user's stuff)